# Wallpaper change code not working

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

The line wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wall1); gives error (red line on R.drawable.wall1)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper_set);

    bSet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWall);

    bSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(WallpaperSet.this);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.wall1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `gives error (red line on R.drawable.wall1)` doesn't tell me much.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by numerous things. Starting from not being able to find your image named wall1 in your drawable folder to not being able to properly resolve the R.class.

The second problem should be solved by simply running a rebuild through the menu. The first one is even easier to solve. You just have to put the correct image file to your res/drawable folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change `R.drawable.wall1` to `R.raw.wall1` and paste the image to the raw folder.

```
wallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.wall1);
```